# Print pdf on schedule automatically

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, printing, cron

I want schedule PDF print in my PHP MySQL application, let me explain in details.

In working hours I have set 50 pdf which I want to print after 12:00 AM, because in working hours printer is busy.

So how I can set schedule print pdf using PHP, I required directly call command from the server using CRON job so no required to On my PC.

Please help me.

Comment: Is the server connected to a printer? What is the operating system on the server? My guess is that the server is not connected to a printer and that the operating system is a Linux variant. If so, you CAN'T print from the server because it is not connected to a printer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cronjob with this setup:

```
* 0 * * * [user] [path to your php] [path to your php script]
```

Comment: Cron is fine, I will do it but how print my document using cron, cron will run at 11:59 then no one have in office,

Comment: ! youre looking for `system('lpr [filename]');` but the printer has to be configured on the server